# Choosing the user's installation folder of a program deployed with Visual Studio

Tags: winforms, deployment, path, visual-studio-2013, clickonce

I am using Visual Studio 2013. This is a WinForms program.

When the users run the installation of my program (located on a shared drive), it is automatically installed to a cumbersome path with randomly generated characters, such as: D:\users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\fezgfizegfiezfuifihfzuelhfezlihfuze\hfuhezfhzelihfilze\programname.exe

I would like to make it be installed to a simpler path, such as: %userprofile%\programname\programname.exe

However I can't seem to find where to set that up.

I have looked through all the tabs of the project's Properties, but couldn't find what I was looking for.

If that helps, the program is deployed using ClickOnce, because it allows auto-updates whenever a new build is available.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.